TCP connection pooling setup with proper reconnection config for connections reconnecting on same source port as before
So I am trying to setup connection pooling so that I can test my application with a whole lot more requests without hitting file descriptor and other limits on my machine (M1 Macbook air).
Now the connection pooling I wanted to implement closes the connection when returned back to the pool after been used for a request, because, this connection pooling implementation is used by test client which interacts with a server and server by default closes the connection on it's end after each request, as it should. Well it's debatable, but in my application server does not need to keep the connection open any longer than it has to. So we are also closing the connection when returned which should free up the file descriptor and then we create a new connection and bind it to the same source port as the previous one.
Here is the code of my current connection pooling class, will talk about the comments later below.
import socket
from queue import Queue, Empty
import threading
import time
import struct
class ConnectionPool:
    def __init__(self, ip, port, pool_size=10,source_port_start=30000,source_port_end=40000):
        self.ip = ip
        self.port = port
        self.pool_size = pool_size
        self.source_port_start = source_port_start
        self.next_source_port = source_port_start
        self.source_port_end = source_port_end
        self.pool = Queue(maxsize=pool_size)
        self.lock = threading.Lock() 
        self._create_pool()
        

    def _create_pool(self):
        for _ in range(self.pool_size):
            conn = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
            # Attempt to bind to a unique source port within range
            with self.lock:
                for port in range(self.next_source_port, self.source_port_end):
                    try:
                        conn.bind(('', port))
                        # print(f"Bound to source port: {port}")
                        self.next_source_port = port + 1
                        break
                    except OSError as e:
                        print(f"Port {port} is in use, trying next port.")
                        continue
                else:
                    print("No available ports in range.")
                    conn.close()
                    return None  # No available port to bind
            
            try:
                conn.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
                # conn.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_KEEPALIVE, 10)
                # Set TCP keep-alive parameters
                # This might require platform-specific configuration
                # Setting the keep-alive intervals

                # Keep idle time before sending the first keepalive probe (in seconds)

                # Interval between keepalive probes (in seconds)
                # conn.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_TCP, socket.TCP_KEEPINTVL, 10)

                # Maximum number of keepalive probes before declaring the connection dead
                # conn.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_TCP, socket.TCP_KEEPCNT, 10)
                conn.connect((self.ip, self.port))
                self.pool.put((conn, port))
            except socket.error as e:
                print(f"Connection failed: {e}")
                conn.close()
    
    def get_connection(self):
        try:
            return self.pool.get_nowait()
        except Empty:
            return None

    def return_connection(self, conn_tuple):
        # Close the socket forcefully
        conn_tuple[0].setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_LINGER, struct.pack('ii', 1, 0))
        conn_tuple[0].close()
        conn = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        conn.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
        # conn.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_KEEPALIVE, 10) check if source port
        conn.bind(('', conn_tuple[1]))
        conn.connect((self.ip, self.port))
        # if not self.pool.full():
        #     self.pool.put((conn,conn_tuple[1]))
        self.pool.put((conn,conn_tuple[1]))

    def close_all(self):
        while not self.pool.empty():
            conn_tuple = self.pool.get_nowait()
            conn_tuple[0].close()

as you can see the return connection method closes the connection and reopens the connection and binds it to same source port as before.
The problem is, when I use this implementation, it works up until 2000 requests made concurrently, but as I bump up the number of requests to 4000 and above it hangs at some point and I have to exit with sig int signal.
I am more inclined to believe that it has to do with the way we close and reopen the connection, maybe there needs to be some extra configuration with sockets that I am not aware of here.
Every time I exit with sig int the error log shows something was wrong with the conn.recv call and I do not think the issue is on my test logic, I think something is wrong with the connection itself, which was obviously made either in create connection on return connection method.
Now regarding what all I tried so far, first
conn.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
without this option it was not even able to handle upto 200 concurrent request which I think can be addressed as, the connection, even though close has been called on it, it still might take a couple few extra cpu cycles for it to truly close because of TIME_WAIT state to prevent delayed packets being delivered to new connection and if another one opens up in the meantime this option will let us bind to port that is still in TIME_WAIT state.
As you can see, an attempt was also made to make the connections long lived using keep alive and probes but that was a failure as tests started stalling way sooner. I don't know how to explain that, but it is for the better I guess since we want to close the connection right away after use and reconnect with a new connection , and making those connections long lived would be in contradiction with what we are trying to do , I could be wrong here though.
And most important and the change that made the first 2000 concurrent request test even possible was the use of
conn_tuple[0].setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_LINGER, struct.pack('ii', 1, 0))
this option before actually calling close.
This forces the socket to close immediately discarding any unsent data.
Without this tests were hanging midway way more frequently and was not even able to test upto 100 concurrent requests properly, with a pool size of 10.
after these changes the test was able to run for 2000 concurrent requests with a pool size of 10 successfully.
Also tried
 if conn_tuple[0].fileno() != -1:
        try:
            # Try setting SO_LINGER to close the socket gracefully
            conn_tuple[0].setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_LINGER, struct.pack('hh', 1, 0))
        except OSError as e:
            print(f"Warning: SO_LINGER failed with error {e}")

Here I was trying to see if there were any errors when this option was being set, and there were sometimes and log message said "Warning: SO_LINGER failed with error invalid argument", couldn't figure out what it was.
But it fails for 4000 and above , so how do we fix and improve it so that it can make use of the pool for theoretically speaking to upto even a million.

Rapidely recycling the same source port for a new connection to the same destination is asking for trouble.  There is expected to be a delay of 2MSL, i.e. 120s, see the TCP standard. There is a reason you can only doing this by forcing it with SO_REUSEADDR - because without this the OS would refuse it for a good reason. While it might look good from the perspective of your code other systems will have problems when a client will behave like this, which might result in simply dropping connection attempts with a recently used source port.

So would you say a fix would be to not force it to bind to same port instead let the os handle assigning source ports for connections.

Exactly, let the OS do the right thing instead of enforcing the wrong thing.

Even with that change it still stalls and hangs when we bump up the number of requests to 4000

I assume that with "hang" you mean that it blocks in connect (if not please be more specific). And if In interprete your code correctly you are trying to use a huge pool of pre-established TCP connections to the same server. What makes you think that a) the server can handle that much TCP connections at the same time and b) will not close connections from the pool simply because they are idle?

"so that I can test my application with a whole lot more requests without hitting file descriptor and other limits on my machine" - I'm not sure how a pool should achieve this. Each new socket will still take a file descriptor, each closed socket will release a file descriptor. Having a pool does not magically increase the number of usable connections, and thus also not the number of requests (since in your case each connection will do only a single request)

Also note that TCP keep alive (which you attempted to use) has absolutely nothing to do with issuing multiple requests over the same TCP connection. You might confuse this with HTTP keep alive which is a completely different mechanism.

I have a progress bar implemented in my test client, which tracks the progress of how far we are into the tests , and what I meant by hangs is that at some point the progress bar freezes. Now regarding the number of pre established connections, I was able to achieve 2000 concurrent requests with successful response with just 10 connections and I was hoping it would work till 10000. I want to have my test client test at least upto 10000. Which seems reasonable even for a macbook air.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
